# Impossible to checkout a git commit

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm trying to checkout a specific commit that I see on GitHub:

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/commit/b8907e79fc3fb52803b5a05c106948911dcd77ac

However, a local checkout fails:

```
$ git checkout b8907e79fc3fb52803b5a05c106948911dcd77ac
fatal: reference is not a tree: b8907e79fc3fb52803b5a05c106948911dcd77ac
```

A `git reset` failed with the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That commit *was* in that repository at one time.

It was subsequently *deleted* from the repository, so new clones of that repository do not get that particular commit.  (Deletion is a bit tricky, but for example, this can happen because a pull request gets modified—the commit *was* there because of the pull request, then the pull request itself gets updated with new-and-improved commits.  The replacement commit is the one ultimately used, and the original expires on its own after a few more days.)

It still is present on GitHub because GitHub does not always clean out everything immediately.  In this case, however, they have not cleaned things out for quite a long time, and it's not clear why it's still accessible via the GitHub web interface at all.  This commit is not reachable from a pull request either (there are 218 pull requests hanging on to commits but this is not among them).  I wonder if links from "issues" pages might also keep otherwise-unreachable commits alive, on GitHub.

Following this commit backwards, through its parent links on GitHub, reveals a whole sequence of commits that seem to have been replaced with new-and-improved versions at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how frequently GitHub runs a `git gc` in each of its repository, that commit, if it was deleted, might still be on GitHub side.

A trick would then be to use the [GitHub Tags API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) to [create a tag object](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/#create-a-tag-object) for that old commit.

You could the do a [`git fetch --tags`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--t), and that would be enough to enable a local checkout of that commit.